# Closure subspace proof easy, but I am overlooking something

Tags: general-topology

> **Theorem**: Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$; let $A$ be a subset of $Y$; let $\bar{A}$ denote the closure of $A$ in $X$. Then the closure of $A$ in $Y$ equals $\bar{A}\cap Y$.
>
> **Proof**: Let $B$ denote the closure of $A$ in $Y$. The set $\bar{A}$ is closed in $X$, so $\bar{A} \cap Y$ is closed in $Y$. Since $\bar{A} \cap Y$ contains $A$, and since by definition $B$ equals the intersection of all closed sets in $Y$ containing $A$, **we must have $B \subset \bar{A} \cap Y$**. On the other hand, we know that $B$ is closed in $Y$. Then $B = C \cap Y$ for some closed set $C$ in $X$. **Then $C$ is a closed set of $X$ containing $A$;** because $\bar{A}$ is the intersection of all such closed sets. Then we have $\bar{A} \cap Y \subset C \cap Y = B.$

Would someone explain the bolded part to me? I don't understand why $B$ being the smallest closed set containing $A$ in $Y$, implies the inclusion, and just how do we know $C$ contains $A$? Is it because by definition $B$ is in both $C$ **and** $Y$ and by the definition of $B$ we must contain $A$?

Why is it not a good idea to prove $B = B \cup B' = \bar{A} \cap Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A\subseteq B$ and $A\subseteq\overline A$ and $A\subseteq Y$. Therefore $A\subseteq\overline A\cap Y$. But since $B$ is the smallest set which is closed in $Y$ and contains $A$, it follows that $B\subseteq\overline A\cap Y$.

On the other hand, by definition of relatively closed sets, there is a set $C\subseteq X$ which closed and $C\cap Y=B$. But since $A\subseteq B$ we have that $A\subseteq C$. And again since the closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set containing it we have that $\overline A\subseteq C$; and therefore $\overline A\cap Y\subseteq C\cap Y=B$.

Comment: Wait how does $B$ being the smallest closed set in $Y$ and containing $A$ imply $B \subset \bar{A}$ also?

Comment: Recall that $\overline A\cap Y$ is a closed set in $Y$ which contains $A$.

Comment: Yes, $A \subset \bar{A} \cap Y$ as you have wrote, but the line that follow doesn't make sense to me still...

Comment: Read it again, whenever there is a mathematical term, don't assume you know it, read its definition twice before applying it to the context. This is not a long sentence, so it shouldn't take more than half an hour. This way you won't just understand this problem, but you will gain skills to deal with many more problems.

Comment: The definition I am getting right now is that $A \subset B \subset Y$, I am not seeing why $B \subset \bar{A}$ also.

Comment: Do you agree that $B\subseteq\overline A\cap Y$?

Comment: No, I do agree that $B \subset Y$, but I don't see how $B$ being the *smallest closed set* **in $Y$** and containing $A$ implies also that $B \subset \bar{A}$. BUt if you work backwards for me, I might understand.

Comment: Do you agree that $A$ is a subset of $\overline A$? Do you agree that $\overline A$ is closed? Do you agree that the intersection of a closed set with $Y$ is relatively closed there?

Comment: (Also, unless you wire me some cash I don't see how I can work for you. And I don't intend to give you the solution. My plan is to push you close enough to the door that you'll see it and be able to go through it on your own.)

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, all definitions.

Comment: If you agree with all three questions then I have nothing to add. Take an hour to think about it.

Comment: Alright, I will try harder and report back to you.

Comment: Good. In the meantime, I have another reality to explore for two hours.

Comment: Any progress so far?

Comment: I think so. Here is my response. $\bar{A} \cap Y$ is a closed set in $Y$, and because $B$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$, it must be a subset of $\bar{A} \cap Y$ because $B$ is the intersection of one of those sets, namely $\bar{A} \cap Y$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.